# Generating probabilities with support -1 to 1

Tags: r, probability, dataset, simulation, random-generation

I have a question about data generation. It seems so simple, but is confusing me.

I am trying to generate data on the probability scale with support of -1, 1. The justification of having this support is that the data is designed to reflect probability of treatment response, which can be positive or negative in direction. I have "known" predictors of treatment response.

Currently, I have a regression model with predictors of a treatment response, which I am treating as a logit. This is then converted to probability scale. This is problematic because it makes the support 0,1.

Here is sample code for generation:

```
X  = rbinom(N*p, 1, .5)
df = data.frame(matrix(X, nrow=N, ncol=p))
df$obs.txt = rep(0:1,N/2)
df$TE = (-2.1*df$X1 + -1.4*df$X2 + -.5*df$X3 + .3*df$X4 + .9*df$X5 + 1.6*df$X6 + 
         1.9*df$X7)
df$pTE = 1/(1+exp(-1*(df$TE)))
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to better generate this data?

Comment: Why not just multiply by 2 and subtract 1?

Comment: You're conflating "probability of treatment response" with "measure of treatment response". A a certain but negative treatment response has probability 1, not -1. Keep probabilities in [0,1] and think more carefully about defining what you actually want to measure.